# How to put single border around multiple elements in constraint layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-constraintlayout

With Android's constraint layout, how can I put a single border around multiple elements? One of the main benefits of constraint layout is that you don't have to nest views. Is this the one scenario where you would use another layout inside of constraint layout?

Comment: Not really. You can do this without nesting. But again a lot will depend on how your layout actually looks

Comment: https://constraintlayout.github.io/cookbook/background.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing more of your code it is hard for me to know what your actual layout looks like. But this is one way to draw a border around some layouts without nesting any of the views

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.7"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/v1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="#8FF0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/v2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="#8F0F"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/v3"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="#80FF"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/v1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/v4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="#8000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/v5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/v2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/v1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/v5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="#8000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/v3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/v1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/v2" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is how the output looks like

[image]

Those colored views are some some widgets that have been placed in the layout. And the border has been set in another view.